# Shopware 6 Plugin: How to Implement Custom Fields for Customers?

Tags: symfony, symfony4, shopware, shopware6

I'm working on a Shopware 6 project where I need to implement custom fields for customers. The task involves creating a custom field set named "Swag Customer" with two additional fields: "Purchase on invoice" and "Purchase on direct debit".

The requirements are:

[image]

I am little confused should I create these fields in the `config.xml` or create them in a `PHP` file?

`config.xml`

```xml
<custom-fields>
    <custom-field-set name="Swag Kunden" entity="customer">
        <custom-field name="custom_swag_customer_purchaseoninvoice" type="checkbox">
            <label lang="en">Purchase on invoice</label>
        </custom-field>
        <custom-field name="custom_swag_customer_purchaseondirectdebit" type="checkbox">
            <label lang="en">Purchase on direct debit</label>
        </custom-field>
    </custom-field-set>
</custom-fields>
```

`CustomFieldClass.php` as shown on [here](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/custom-field/add-custom-field.html)

```php
use Shopware\Core\System\CustomField\CustomFieldTypes;
use Shopware\Core\Defaults;

// Create custom field set
$this->customFieldSetRepository->create([
    [
        'name' => 'custom_swag_customer', // Technical name of the custom field set
        'config' => [
            'label' => [
                'en-GB' => 'swag Customer', // English custom field set label
                Defaults::SYSTEM_LANGUAGE => 'swag Customer' // Fallback label
            ]
        ],
        'customFields' => [
            [
                'name' => 'custom_swag_customer_purchaseoninvoice', // Technical name of the custom field
                'type' => CustomFieldTypes::BOOL, // Data type of the custom field (checkbox)
                'config' => [
                    'label' => [
                        'en-GB' => 'Purchase on invoice', // English custom field label
                        Defaults::SYSTEM_LANGUAGE => 'Purchase on invoice' // Fallback label
                    ],
                    'customFieldPosition' => 1 // Position of the custom field
                ]
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'custom_swag_customer_purchaseondirectdebit', // Technical name of the custom field
                'type' => CustomFieldTypes::BOOL, // Data type of the custom field (checkbox)
                'config' => [
                    'label' => [
                        'en-GB' => 'Purchase on direct debit', // English custom field label
                        Defaults::SYSTEM_LANGUAGE => 'Purchase on direct debit' // Fallback label
                    ],
                    'customFieldPosition' => 2 // Position of the custom field
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
], $context);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option using **customFieldSetRepository** has to be adopted, since its in the official documentation of Shopware.
*"Additionally just as a note, this should be included in the new plugin that you will create."*